# Python DataFrame: Break down one column using mapping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to take an aggregated time-series and break it down to its component pieces. For example, I have a time series forecast, that I would like to break down between 3 buckets (red,blue,oj)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

index = pd.date_range(start = dt.date.today(), end = dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days = 400), freq = 'M')

df = pd.DataFrame(index = index)
df['Volume'] = [random.randint(340,950) for x in range(len(df))]
df
```

[image]

```
volume_breakdown = pd.Series({
    "red":.5,
    "blue":.3,
    "oj":.2
})
volume_breakdown
```

Trying to multiply:

```
df * volume_breakdown
```

[image]

I know this is related to indexing, but is there a way to do this without using for loops and doing a concat/join/merge?

Edit:
Resolved with answer below,

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df["Volume"].values.reshape((-1, 1)) * volume_breakdown.values, index = index, columns = volume_breakdown.index
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy` to avoid indexing problem:

```
df[volume_breakdown.index] = df["Volume"].values.reshape((-1, 1)) \
                                 * volume_breakdown.values
```

```
>>> df
            Volume    red   blue     oj
2021-05-31     722  361.0  216.6  144.4
2021-06-30     530  265.0  159.0  106.0
2021-07-31     762  381.0  228.6  152.4
2021-08-31     706  353.0  211.8  141.2
2021-09-30     811  405.5  243.3  162.2
2021-10-31     908  454.0  272.4  181.6
2021-11-30     912  456.0  273.6  182.4
2021-12-31     740  370.0  222.0  148.0
2022-01-31     692  346.0  207.6  138.4
2022-02-28     798  399.0  239.4  159.6
2022-03-31     497  248.5  149.1   99.4
2022-04-30     622  311.0  186.6  124.4
2022-05-31     589  294.5  176.7  117.8
```

Comment: While I'm able to get the array/product I'm looking for using the above code, when I try to assign the dataframe columns, I get an error (using python 3.6.5): 

"Index(['red', 'blue', 'oj'], dtype='object') not in index"

Comment: Do you use `.loc` to assign? To use `loc`, index or columns have to exist before.

Comment: I was able to assign it by wrapping the numpy array in a pd.DataFrame()